# Get tail of Row

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In Spark, I have an object of type `org.apache.spark.sql.Row`.

I want to get all the elements of the `Row` object, except for the first one.

`myRow.tail` doesn't work

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The Row object has no method tail or head. Due to is not extends of sequency objects.

The way that you can do is:

```
myRow.toSeq.tail
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

Row.fromSeq(Row.toSeq.tail)
```